# How to use fig.show=animate in knitr without administrator privileges

Tags: r, animation, video, ffmpeg, knitr

I use Windows without administrator privileges hence I cannot set a path in the Windows PATH variable.

The `ffmpeg.exe` file is in my `"U:/ProgramFiles/ImageMagick-6.8.5-5/"` folder.

I have found how to use the `saveVideo()` function of the `animate` package:

```
ani.options(ffmpeg = shQuote('U:/ProgramFiles/ImageMagick-6.8.5-5/ffmpeg.exe'))
saveVideo({
  par(mar = rep(3, 4))
  for (i in seq(pi/2, -4/3 * pi, length = 12)) {
    plot(0, 0, pch = 20, ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE)
    arrows(0, 0, cos(i), sin(i))
    axis(1, 0, "VI"); axis(2, 0, "IX")
    axis(3, 0, "XII"); axis(4, 0, "III"); box()
  }
},
        video.name="mavideo.mp4",
        outdir="U:/Data/Rtests/Animation")
```

But I haven't find how to knit a Rmd file with the option `fig.show=animate` in a chunk, for instance:

````
```{r clock, fig.width=7, fig.height=6, fig.show='animate'}
par(mar = rep(3, 4))
for (i in seq(pi/2, -4/3 * pi, length = 12)) {
    plot(0, 0, pch = 20, ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE)
    arrows(0, 0, cos(i), sin(i))
    axis(1, 0, "VI"); axis(2, 0, "IX")
    axis(3, 0, "XII"); axis(4, 0, "III"); box()
}
```
````

I have tried to modifiy the `hook_ffmpeg_html()` function  by only changing the `ffmpeg.cmd` variable:

````
```{r}
 hook_ffmpeg_html2 <- function (x, options) 
{ 
    ........ 
    ffmpeg.cmd = paste("-y", "-r", 1/options$interval, 
        "-i", fig.fname, mov.fname) 
    ffmpeg.cmd <-  paste('"U:/ProgramFiles/ImageMagick-6.8.5-5/ffmpeg"', ffmpeg.cmd) 
   ...... 
} 
opts_knit$set(animation.fun = hook_ffmpeg_html2) 
```
````

But this chunk does not work, below is the error message :

```
label: unnamed-chunk-1 
Warning in block_exec(params) : 
  failed to tidy R code in chunk <unnamed-chunk-1> 
reason: Error in base::parse(text = text, srcfile = NULL) : 
  21:14: unexpected symbol 
20: options$out.height), if ("controls" %in% mov.opts) 
21: "controls=\\"controls
```

Comment: Can you set user environment path (edit environment variables for your account)?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik No I can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Am transferring this from comments to an answer.)

You don't need Admin privs to set the path for the current process from R. `Sys.setenv(path = "...")` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that you must have the system admin privilege to modify `PATH`. There are two types of environment variables under Windows: User variables and System variables. You do not need admin privilege to modify the former (you can create a variable called `PATH` in that group), and you only need it for the latter.

[image: PATH under Windows]

Comment: Hello Yihui and thank you. How do you get this window ? On Windows XP if I do "Control Panel" -> "System", actually I can't even click on "System".

Comment: When I right-click on "My Computer" there's no "Properties" available.

Comment: However I believe there's a way to modify the path: I have installed Pandoc with a msi installer and the `pandoc`command is recognized by the system.

Comment: Even this keyboard shortcut does not work http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/bc/bcs4p13.html This is the computer from my job, I think everything has been done in order that we don't have access to the system properties. However I wonder how the pandoc msi installer could work ?

Comment: the `setx` command allows you to set environment variables without using the GUI mentioned above